# How to use if else expression to assign different variable name in scala

Tags: scala, if-statement

I'm trying to assign a different variable name for each value returned from the if-else expression. This is because I want to use the return value later in my program and how to use it depends on which branch (if or else) is executed.

For example:

```
if(5<1) {val x = 5;x} else {val y = 1; y}
```

current output:

```
res31: Int = 1
```

Desired output:

```
y: Int = 1
```

Thanks

Comment: What should the value of the other variable be in each case? Like, if the condition is false, what should the value of `x` be? Or is your intent that only one of the variables will be in scope, depending on the condition? If so, do you expect undefined-variable errors to be deferred until run time?

Comment: @sepp2k, if x is false i don't use at all but I use y. so one variable in the Scope.

Comment: Whether a certain variable is in scope or not at some particular position of the code is a question that must be answerable at compile time. The boolean value in the condition of the `if-else` will be evaluated at runtime. Your request is meaningless.

Comment: Why not write `val z = if (5<1) { 5 } else { 1 }` and then only use `z` instead of `x` or `y`? Can you show your complete code where this approach would not work?

Comment: "if x is false i don't use at all but I use y. " How do you ensure that? Do you just put all code that uses `x` or `y` into `if`s that have the same condition? Would you expect the compiler to generate an error if `x` or `y` are used outside of such an `if` (but not if they are used inside such an `if`)? And if not, again, what should the value be? Would you also expect to be able to use `x` or `y` in an `if` with an equivalent (but not syntactically the same) condition?

Comment: Very likely an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `Option` to track what you computed?

```
scala 2.13.0-M4> val (x,y) = if (true) (Some(42), None) else (None, Some(17))
x: Option[Int] = Some(42)
y: Option[Int] = None

scala 2.13.0-M4> x.map(_ + 1).orElse(y.map(_ * 2))
res0: Option[Int] = Some(43)

scala 2.13.0-M4> val (x,y) = if (false) (Some(42), None) else (None, Some(17))
x: Option[Int] = None
y: Option[Int] = Some(17)

scala 2.13.0-M4> x.map(_ + 1).orElse(y.map(_ * 2))
res1: Option[Int] = Some(34)
```

Comment: Better to use `Either` rather than `Option`, since you only ever have one valid value.

Comment: @Tim even better. I forget how to operate on left/right, so next time I'll allocate a half-hour to re-read the scaladoc. Maybe just pattern match.

Comment: You can use fold with an ```Either```. The following is the Either equivalent ```e.fold(_+1,_*2)```

Comment: If you're really keen on the `x` and `y` names, then ```e.fold(x=>x+1,y=>y*2)```

Comment: @Ethan thanks I'll try to update the answer some morning when SO isn't too depressing. My previous comment was germane, I don't use Either often enough to write a quickie answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do this using `Either`, as discussed in various comments.

Create an instance of `Either` based on a condition:

```
val e = Either.cond(5 < 1, 5, 1)
```

This is either `Right(...)` or `Left(...)` depending on the condition. In this case `e` is `Left(1)`.

The values are in the order `right`, `left` because it is "right-biased" and `Right` is the "normal" value and `Left` is the "exceptional" value. So if you are using `Either` to return a result or an error condition then the result would, by convention, be `Right(result)` and the error would be `Left(error)`. (Presumably because `Right` is "right" and so `Left` is "wrong").

You can think of `Either` as like `Option` where `Right` is `Some` but instead of `None` you have another value, `Left`. Methods like `foreach`/`contains`/`exists` only operate if the value is `Right`. The `Try` type has a method `toEither` that will return either `Right(success)` or `Left(exception)`.

To unpick the value, use a `match` statement:

```
e match {
  case Right(x) =>
    println(s"Right: x=$x")
  case Left(y) =>
    println(s"Left: y=$y")
}
```

To compute a value using either `Left` or `Right` use fold:

```
val res = e.fold(y => y + 1, x => x*2)
```

In this case `res` is `2`. Confusingly, the arguments here are in the order `Left` then `Right`, the opposite order from `cond`.